# How to get masklen from model

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

the model as below to store the ip address in postgres.

```
from django.db import models
from netfields import InetAddressField, CidrAddressField, NetManager

class TestModel(models.Model):
    client_ip = InetAddressField(default='0.0.0.0/0', store_prefix_length=True)
```

I want to get the IP masklength directly through the model.
but I can't find a attribute correspondig to postgresql inet masklen
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-net.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the masklength from single object you can define your model like:

```
from ipaddress import ip_interface

from django.db import models
from netfields import InetAddressField, CidrAddressField, NetManager

class TestModel(models.Model):
    client_ip = InetAddressField(default=ip_interface('0.0.0.0/0'), store_prefix_length=True)

    @property
    def masklength(self):
        return self.client_ip.network.prefixlen
```

Example:

```
obj = TestModel(client_ip=ip_interface('192.168.1.0/24'))
obj.masklength # 24
```

Note that [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) is builtin in Python 3.3+, so if you are using older version you will have to install [this](https://pypi.org/project/ipaddress/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own [`Func`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) to add this function to your project:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField, Func


class MaskLen(Func):
    function = 'MASKLEN'

    def __init__(self, output_field=None, **extra):
        if output_field is None:
            output_field = IntegerField()
        super(TransactionNow, self).__init__(output_field=output_field, **extra)
```

Then use it as follows: `qs.annotate(mask_length=MaskLen('client_ip'))`